# Filter Parameters and Attributes return (null)

Tags: objective-c, core-image, cifilter

I am studying the CIFilter class, I'm testing some commands in this class that can be found in its documentation on this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CIFilter/attributes).

Regarding the part that talks about "Getting Filter Parameters and Attributes", I'm having some problems with the commands: **attributes, inputKeys, outputKeys, name**. For that I try this code below:

```
CIFilter *filtro2 = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBoxBlur" keysAndValues:@"inputImage",image, @"inputRadius",45.0, nil];

 NSLog(@"Filter Attributes -> %@",filtro2.attributes);
 NSLog(@"Filter inputKeys -> %@",filtro2.inputKeys);
 NSLog(@"Filter outputKeys -> %@",filtro2.outputKeys);
 NSLog(@"Filter Name -> %@",filtro2.name);
```

The problem is that the console is always returning me a **null value**, why? I'm using these commands in the wrong way? How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I stared at the code a while before I saw the bug:
All the values after keysAndValues: must be objects.  The 45.0 should be @45.0